# What's the equivalent of sed -n 'np' file in perl

Tags: perl, sed

Via sed,one can obtain the n'th line from a file.

```
sed -n '40p' file;
A=$(sed -n '40p' file);
```

what is the equivalent for this in perl?

Comment: Note that it's better to quit if you want to read a specific line, i.e. use `sed -n '40pq'` instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
perl -ne '$. ==40 and print' file
```

or you can skip lines less than 40, print desired line, and stop file processing,

```
perl -ne 'next if $. <40; print; last' file
```

Comment: What if i want to assign it to an array or scaler variable?

Comment: @computer10 `$line = $_` instead of `print` if you want to assign to some variable. btw, do you want to assign to shell variable?

Comment: I want to assign it to variable inside perl script.

Comment: This is equivalent to `sed -n '40pq'` :)

Comment: @devnull tnx for the info.

Comment: @devnull can you suggest some perl2sed guide? :)

Comment: Now you are kidding, aren't you?

Comment: it can also be sed2perl, just to check some common idioms

Comment: I didn't realize that [`s2p`](http://perldoc.perl.org/s2p.html) actually does quite a bit.

Answer (score 5):

This could be one

```
perl -ne 'print if $. == 40'
```

`$.` is the line number of current input stream.